# Data structure indexing (like as in relational databases)

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, hashmap, relational-database

Consider a data structure like:

```
structure = {
  1: {"a": "xy", "b": 123},
  2: {"a": "rt", "b": 222},
  3: {"a": "fd", "b": 111},
}
```

Suppose we want to search a row in this structure by given value of `a`.

In a relational database we would just make the row `a` indexed and this makes the operation fast.

What about such support of "indexed rows" in programming languages and/or programming libraries (without supporting full-blown relational database, I mean mainly without support of SQL)? Which languages and/or libraries do support this?

I know I can create an additional "map" data structure with references to the objects in the above datastructure, but my question is how not to do it manually (without creating a new map for every key). How to automate this task? (One thing is to create an object which would hold all necessary hashes and maps, but is there an easier way?)

(The example data structure is small and does not require hashes for search, but it gives the general idea.)

Comment: Ultimately, you're going to end up with a separate hash map (or equivalent) for every field you want to index. As you say, you could do that explicitly. I'm not familiar with any programming language that gives you such functionality out of the box, but you could implement it without much trouble in some languages that support reflection. You have to be careful, though, to ensure that any such indexed fields are not modified after the index is created.

Answer (score 0):

Use a B-Tree with key value of a. It will sort the data in the B-Tree according to value of a. Database management systems implement the primary index in the same way. The data is physically stored in order of the primary index (or primary key) in B-Trees. Moreover, you can store the B-Tree in a memory mapped file on disk. This is how the DBMS creates a primary index.